# Docker compose app with PostgreSQL : Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
I have already tried several things and am frustrated with the problem.
I'd love for someone to take a look to see what I'm doing wrong.
The tests I did:
Port 5423 is correct and open (not blocked by the firewall)

Some information about the code
docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:15.1-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db_name
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      NextRoofWeb_CORE_SETTING_DATABASES: '{"default":{"HOST":"db"}}'
      NextRoofWeb_CORE_SETTING_LOCAL_SETTINGS_PATH: 'core/NextRoofWeb/settings/base.py'

volumes:
  postgresql-data:
    driver: local
```

base.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'passwords',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work?  Databases can take some time to start up, and you can get a "connection refused" error if the application starts faster.  Also see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).